# How to resolve "iterator should return strings, not bytes"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, iterator

I am trying to import a CSV file, using a form to upload the file from the client system. After I have the file, I'll take parts of it and populate a model in my app. However, I'm getting an "iterator should return strings, not bytes" error when I go to iterate over the lines in the uploaded file.  I've spent hours trying different things and reading everything I could find on this but can't seem resolve it (note, I'm relatively new to Django- running 1.5- and python - running 3.3).  I stripped out things to get to just the error and ran it like this to make sure it is still there. The error is displayed when executing the line "for clubs in club_list" in tools_clubs_import():

**The following is the corrected views.py that works, based on answer marked below:**

```
import csv
from io import TextIOWrapper
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from rank.forms import ClubImportForm

def tools_clubs_import(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClubImportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # the following 4 lines dumps request.META to a local file
            # I saw a lot of questions about this so thought I'd post it too
            log = open("/home/joel/meta.txt", "w")
            for k, v in request.META.items():
                print ("%s: %s\n" % (k, request.META[k]), file=log)
            log.close()
            # I found I didn't need errors='replace', your mileage may vary
            f = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['filename'].file,
                    encoding='ASCII')
            club_list = csv.DictReader(f)
            for club in club_list:
                # do something with each club dictionary entry
                pass
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rank.views.tools_clubs_import_show'))
    else:
        form = ClubImportForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'active_menu_item': 4,}
    return render(request, 'rank/tools_clubs_import.html', context)

def tools_clubs_import_show(request):
    return render(request, 'rank/tools_clubs_import_show.html')
```

The following is the original version of what I submitted (the html that generates the form is included at the bottom of this code list:

```
views.py
--------
import csv
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from rank.forms import ClubImportForm

def tools(request):
    context = {'active_menu_item': 4,}
    return render(request, 'rank/tools.html', context)

def tools_clubs(request):
    context = {'active_menu_item': 4,}
    return render(request, 'rank/tools_clubs.html', context)

def tools_clubs_import(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClubImportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = request.FILES['filename']
            club_list = csv.DictReader(f)
            for club in club_list:
                # error occurs before anything here is executed
                # process here... not included for brevity
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rank.views.tools_clubs_import_show'))
    else:
        form = ClubImportForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'active_menu_item': 4,}
    return render(request, 'rank/tools_clubs_import.html', context)

def tools_clubs_import_show(request):
    return render(request, 'rank/tools_clubs_import_show.html')

forms.py
--------
from django import forms


class ClubImportForm(forms.Form):
    filename = forms.FileField(label='Select a CSV to import:',)


urls.py
-------
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rank import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^tools/$', views.tools, name='rank-tools'),
    url(r'^tools/clubs/$', views.tools_clubs, name='rank-tools_clubs'),
    url(r'^tools/clubs/import$',
        views.tools_clubs_import,
        name='rank-tools_clubs_import'),
    url(r'^tools/clubs/import/show$',
        views.tools_clubs_import_show,
        name='rank-tools_clubs_import_show'),
)


tools_clubs_import.html
-----------------------
{% extends "rank/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Tools/Club/Import{% endblock %}
{% block center_col %}

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{% url 'rank-tools_clubs_import' %}">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Exception Value:

iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python3.3/csv.py in fieldnames, line 96

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`request.FILES` gives you *binary* files, but the `csv` module wants to have text-mode files instead.

You need to wrap the file in a [`io.TextIOWrapper()` instance](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper), and you need to figure out the encoding:

```
from io import TextIOWrapper

f = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['filename'].file, encoding=request.encoding)
```

It'd probably be better if you took the `charset` parameter from the `Content-Type` header if provided; that is what the client tells you the character set is.

You cannot work around needing to know the correct encoding for the file data; you can force interpretation as ASCII, for example, by providing a `errors` keyword as well (setting it to 'replace' or 'ignore'), but that does lead to data loss:

```
f = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['filename'].file, encoding='ascii', errors='replace')
```

Using TextIOWrapper will only work when using Django 1.11 and later (as [this changeset added the required support](https://github.com/django/django/commit/4f474607de9b470f977a734bdd47590ab202e778)). In earlier versions, you can monkey-patch the support in after the fact:

```
from django.core.files.utils import FileProxyMixin

if not hasattr(FileProxyMixin, 'readable'):
    # Pre-Django 1.11, add io.IOBase support, see
    # https://github.com/django/django/commit/4f474607de9b470f977a734bdd47590ab202e778        
    def readable(self):
        if self.closed:
            return False
        if hasattr(self.file, 'readable'):
            return self.file.readable()
        return True

    def writable(self):
        if self.closed:
            return False
        if hasattr(self.file, 'writable'):
            return self.file.writable()
        return 'w' in getattr(self.file, 'mode', '')

    def seekable(self):
        if self.closed:
            return False
        if hasattr(self.file, 'seekable'):
            return self.file.seekable()
        return True

    FileProxyMixin.closed = property(
        lambda self: not self.file or self.file.closed)
    FileProxyMixin.readable = readable
    FileProxyMixin.writable = writable
    FileProxyMixin.seekable = seekable
```

Comment: That generates "'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'readable'".

Comment: @MeaOrdo: Updated; sorry, I don't have a Django-on-3.x running atm, so it's source-code reading and extrapolation only here. :-)

Comment: I tried several variations on encoding with TextIOWrapper, and using StringIO instead of TextIOWrapper. Different encodings on TextIOWrapper give an Unable to decode at byte 10 error and all variations using StringIO give TypeErrors, and some combinations refer to the "InMemoryUploadedFile". Is the error actually at the request.FILES['filename'] stage? Passing that to csv.DictReader doesn't generate an error until you try to iterate over the result.

Comment: @MeaOrdo: Iteration starts the reading; you ask `csv` for a row, and the module then asks the file for data. The `InMemoryUploadedFile` object acts as a proxy for the actual file object, a `io.BytesIO` object. You do need to wrap that object with `TextIOWrapper` but you *have* to find out the proper encoding. If all else fails use `TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['filename'].file, encoding='ASCII', errors='replace')`. Have you looked at `request.META. CONTENT_TYPE` at all to see if there is a `charset` parameter specified?

Comment: Martijn, I really appreciate the comments and help here.  This seems far more difficult than it should be, and I hope that I'm not the one making it that way.  The basics of what I want has to be a VERY common requirement - Request a filename from the client browser and upload the CSV file from their system and then use that CSV file to update a model.  Am I going about this the correct way? I'm all ears if there's a better way!

Comment: You are going about it the correct way, but you cannot ignore the encoding. If your client uploads international data, you need to be able to read that as Unicode.

Comment: The TextIOWrapper above, with encoding='ASCII' works. Looking at the request.META data wasn't very helpful.  The CONTENT_TYPE is set from my forms ENCTYPE with the addition of a boundary= setting.  No encoding at all.  The only encoding to be found in the request.META was in wsgi.errors: encoding='UTF-8'. Thanks for the help, I'm off and running!

Comment: @Jonathan: thanks for the edits; a heads-up would have done too though. I've added a work-around.

Comment: The encoding should be here: `request.FILES['filename'].charset`

Comment: This worked for me using Django 3.0.2 and Python 3.7

Answer (score 31):

In python 3, I used:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
csvf = StringIO(xls_file.read().decode())
reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',')
```

xls_file being the file got from the POST form. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fuse your two methods, this never fails in Python 3.5.2 and Django 1.9

```
delimitador = list_delimitadores[int(request.POST['delimitador'])][1]
try:
    text = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['csv_x'].file, encoding='utf-8 ', errors='replace')
    reader = csv.reader(text, delimiter=delimitador)
except:
    text = StringIO(request.FILES['csv_x'].file.read().decode())
    reader = csv.reader(text, delimiter=delimitador)
```

Comment: Per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), please don't use bare `except` clauses -- what exception(s) are you expecting specifically?