# django 1.5 how to read csv from memory

Tags: django, file-upload, csv

I am trying to find out how to read an uploaded CSV without saving it to disk ...

I'm stuck at form.cleaned_data['file'].read ... I don't seem to get any output

If I can only figure out how to get output, then I can write an appropriate function to deal with the lines of data.

```
#addreport.html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/products/addreport/">   {%csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form.as_table }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
#
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file  = forms.FileField()
```

--

```
# views.py
def addreport(request):
if request and request.method == "POST":
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
               print form.cleaned_data['file'].read()
    else:
        print form.errors
        print request.FILES
        #form = UploadFileForm()
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()

return render_to_response('products/addreport.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have pretty similar setup for one of my project. Do you have any clean method in your form?

Otherwise I think you can read the file from `form.cleaned_data['file']` just fine:

```
import csv

def addreport(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            reader = csv.reader(form.cleaned_data['file'])
            for row in reader:
                print row
        else:
            print form.errors
            print request.FILES
            #form = UploadFileForm()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    return render(request, 'products/addreport.html', {'form': form})
```

If it doesn't work, try to use `request.FILES['file']` directly instead of `form.cleaned_data['file']`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I assume that you are still testing in your localhost? you should be able to see something in the terminal (result of `print row`).

Comment: I'm actually testing on OpenShift

Comment: Hmm I take it as you can't see the terminal output then. What do you want to do with the output of the csv?

Comment: The issue is that I did not realize that Django does not put out raw output unless its an HTTP response.

Comment: Was getting `iterator should return strings, not bytes` on python 3.5. Solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/16243182/3148949

Answer (score -2):

Can you try:

```
import csv

#In your view
line_reader = csv.reader(form.cleaned_data['file'])
for row in line_reader:
    #do something with each row.
```

Comment: the csv module is not a callable