# Using Ajax to load file in Django framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

My project is dealing with Django, there is a functionality which need to load a file and show the file content in a textarea. Reference to below code.
upload a file then show in "Text_To_Show" item. I do not want to store the file in the server side or database.So my idea is: using ajax to post the file (content) to the view.py then HTTPResponse(data) back to the page.

## form.py

```
class RequestForm(forms.Form):
       Text=forms.CharField(label='Text',widget=forms.Textarea(attrs{'cols':80, 'rows':8 }),max_length=2048,required=False)
       file = forms.FileField()
       Text_To_Show = forms.CharField(label='Text_To_Show',widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={readonly':True}),required=False)
```

## views.py

```
        if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
           form = RequestCertForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
           if form.has_changed():
              print request.FILES
              return HttpResponse('FileContent')
```

## Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#id_file").change(function(){
          $.ajax({
            method : 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(result){
             $("#id_text_to_show").val(result);
          },
           fail: function(result){
              $("#id_text_to_show").val(result);
          }
      });
    });
  });
```

based on the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/
which need method "POST" and enctype: 'multipart/form-data',But my question is why I could not get file content(data) from **request.FILES**. Anyone who has ever expert on this. could you let me know?

Comment: You don't seem to be sending any data in the ajax POST.

Comment: yes, because based on the doc ** request.FILES  ** will only contain data if the request method was POST and the <form> that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty. By the way, do you have any idea transfer file content via ajax?

Comment: Just a question but if you don't want to store the file, why not parsing it directly with javascript on the client side?

Comment: No, you haven't understood how Ajax works. The POST you do inside your JS has nothing at all to do with the content of the form itself; it's completely separate. You have to explicitly tell jQuery what data to POST, usually with the `data:` parameter.

Comment: @zom-pro yeah, Trying to use FileReader to directly parsing the file. while, 1, some browser would not support this Javascript API. 2, Insecure to read the file directly

Comment: @Danie Roseman, usind data: <filecontent>. how to get filecontent here? Only size and name could get here.

Comment: don't parse your answer return as html content.
Django already returned html, why convert file object ?
Only dont forget : never use a class for ajax answer container

Comment: I think @SDilmac is right, you should handle it directly from html without parsing. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159090/django-1-5-how-to-read-csv-from-memory.

Comment: form.cleaned_data['file'] is None, could not be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the idea which use FileReader to directly parsing the file.